# Is it safe to use PUT and DELETE requests

Tags: plugin-development, http, rest-api

I am building my new shiny plugin and since I've read about REST etc.I wanted to do things right and implement PUT and DELETE requests, and not just use POST and GET like I did until now.

But now I am wondering is it safe to use those. And by safe, I mean, are those requests supported by all servers in general.

I don't want to implement everything now only to figure out later that just because of my wish to follow semantics my product is unusable for half of my customers.

Thank you

Comment: Not really a WordPress question. I mean, you're building a WordPress plugin yes, but is this question better suited to a server-specific site like ServerFault?

Comment: You might as well be right, excuse my ignorance. I was so into my question that I did not for a second think there might be a more appropriated place to ask this.

If any mod reads this, is it possible to transfer this q if it does not belong here?

Sorry and thanks

EDIT: Just figured out that you are a moderator, what can be done about this :)

Comment: I have posted the question on serverfault now, feel free to delete this if it's not the best place.Thanks!